# When the eigenvalues of a matrix of blocks are as the eigenvalues of each block

Tags: linear-algebra

Take a look at this matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
10 &-9 & 0 & 0 \\
4&-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &0 & -2 & -7 \\
0 &0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2,3,4}=4,4,\pm j\sqrt{3}$. The eigenvalues of the following blocks 
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
10 &-9 \\
4&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\implies \lambda_{1,2} = 4,4
$$
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &-7 \\
1&2
\end{bmatrix}
\implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm j\sqrt{3}
$$
My question is is is true for any matrix of blocks or is it merely for a matrix of diagonal blocks where the other blocks are zero? A proof will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: It will work for block upper (or lower) triangular as well. The proof follows by noting that $\det(\lambda I - A) = \det(\lambda -A_{11}) \det(\lambda I - A_{22})$.

Comment: Yes, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the product of the characteristic polynomials of $B$ and $C.$